# xampp/php - rsync ssh public passwordless

Tags: php, xampp, rsync, ssh-keys

How can I rsync from php on my development (win/xampp) machine to my testing (Ubuntu) LAMP server using ssh public passwordless key?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. [Set up a key pair](http://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+key+create)
2. Place the proper keys in the proper place -- private on the server, public on the client.
3. ???
4. Profit!  Er, I mean, [rsync](http://www.google.com/search?q=rsync+ssh)!